# Laravel fractal transformers - not getting includes

Tags: laravel, thephpleague-fractal

I am using fractal package in laravel 5.3. I have a player model who has `hasMany` relationship with videos, so one player has many videos.

**Player** model:

```
public function videos()
  {
      return $this->hasMany(Video::class);
  }
```

**Video** model:

```
public function player()
{
    return $this->belongsTo(Player::class);
}
```

I am trying to send player data and include videos data with it. This is the code in the controller:

```
            $player  =  fractal()
                       ->item($player)
                       ->parseIncludes(['videos'])
                       ->transformWith(new PlayerTransformer)
                       ->toArray();
```

And this is the `PlayerTransformer`:

```
<?php

namespace App\Transformer;

use App\Player;

class PlayerTransformer extends \League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract
{
    protected $availableIncludes = [
        'videos'
    ];

    public function transform(Player $player)
    {
        return [
          'id' => $player->id,
          'first_name' => $player->first_name,
          'last_name' => $player->last_name,
          'image' => $player->image_filename,
          'club' => $player->club,
          'birthday' => $player->birthday,
        ];
    }

    public function includeVideos(Player $player)
    {
        $videos = $player->videos()->where('processed', 1)->get();

        return $this->collection($videos, new VideoTransformer);
    }
}
```

I am getting the player data, but I don't get anything for videos. This doesn't work, but what is even weirder if try that with videos, in whose transformer I don't even have includes function:

```
<?php

namespace App\Transformer;

use App\Video;

class VideoTransformer extends \League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract
{
    public function transform(Video $video)
    {
        return [
          'id' => $video->id,
          'uid' => $video->uid,
          'title' => $video->title,
          'image' => $video->getThumbnail(),
          'description' => $video->description,
          'views' => $video->viewCount(),
          'created_at' => $video->created_at->diffForHumans(),
        ];
    }
}
```

But, when I try to include the player data there, that works:

```
              $videos = fractal()
                        ->collection($videos)
                        ->parseIncludes(['player'])
                        ->transformWith(new VideoTransformer)
                        ->toArray();
```

I have tried then to apply the same setup I have for the video transformer and remove the `$availableIncludes` and  `includeVideos`  in the player transfomer, but it again didn't work there. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I liked the original title, "Larval fractal transformers" :)

Comment: `transform` method for `PlayerTransformer` isn't returning an array with videos

Answer (score 0):

I was doing a get without authentication to test my controller and it was giving the error:

***PHP Fatal error:  Type of App\Transformers\CustomerCategoryTransformer::$availableIncludes must be array (as in class League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract) in /app/Transformers/CustomerCategoryTransformer.php on line 8***

I commented out the line:

```
protected $defaultIncludes = [];
protected $availableIncludes = [];
```

**My code:**

```
<?php

namespace App\Transformers;

use App\Models\CustomerCategory;
use League\Fractal\TransformerAbstract;

class CustomerCategoryTransformer extends TransformerAbstract
{
    // protected $defaultIncludes = [];

    // protected $availableIncludes = [];

    public function transform(CustomerCategory $model)
    {
        return [
            'id' => $model->id,
            'uuid' => $model->uuid,
            'seq' => $model->seq,
            'slug' => $model->slug,
            'name' => $model->name,
            'active' => $model->active,
            'created_at' => $model->created_at->toDateTimeString(),
            'updated_at' => $model->updated_at->toDateTimeString(),
        ];
    }
}
```