# Eloquent query optimization

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have below a query build with eloquent on laravel, it is very slow (50 points it take to show around 10 second), i can't understand if it a problem of the query construct or some missing index on table, some advise?
thanks

*Points model (around 5000 records on the table)*

```
    <?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\SoftDeletes;
use OwenIt\Auditing\Contracts\Auditable;

class Points extends Model implements Auditable
{
  use \OwenIt\Auditing\Auditable;
  use SoftDeletes;

  /**
   * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
   *
   * @var bool
   */
  public $timestamps = false;
  /**
   * The database table used by the model.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $table = 'points';

  /**
   * The database primary key value.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $primaryKey = 'id';

  /**
   * Attributes that should be mass-assignable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $fillable = [
    'schedule_id',
    'customer_id',
    'cart_zone_id',
    'indirizzo',
    'latitudine',
    'longitudine',
    'tipo',
    'enabled'
  ];

  /**
   * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $dates = [];

  /**
   * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $casts = [];

  /**
   * Get the Schedule for this model.
   *
   * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
   */
  public function Schedule()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Schedules', 'schedule_id', 'id')->withTrashed();
  }

  /**
   * Get the Customer for this model.
   *
   * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
   */
  public function Customer()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Customers', 'customer_id', 'id')->withTrashed();
  }

  /**
   * Get the CartZone for this model.
   *
   * @return \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo
   */
  public function CartZone()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\CartZones', 'cart_zone_id', 'id')->withTrashed();
  }


}
```

*Events model (around 400k records on the table)*

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Support\Carbon;

class RecordEvents extends Model
{

  /**
   * Indicates if the model should be timestamped.
   *
   * @var bool
   */
  public $timestamps = false;
  /**
   * The database table used by the model.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $table = 'events';

  /**
   * The database primary key value.
   *
   * @var string
   */
  protected $primaryKey = 'id';


  /**
   * Attributes that should be mass-assignable.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $fillable = [
    'code',
    'description',
    'device_id',
    'schedule_id',
    'boa_id',
    'parent_id',
    'user_id',
    'skip_unique'
  ];

  /**
   * The attributes that should be mutated to dates.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $dates = [];

  /**
   * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
   *
   * @var array
   */
  protected $casts = [];

  /**
   * Get the device for this model.
   *
   * @return App\Models\Device
   */
  public function device()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Devices', 'device_id')->withTrashed();
  }

  /**
   * Get the schedule for this model.
   *
   * @return App\Models\Schedule
   */
  public function schedule()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Schedules', 'schedule_id')->withTrashed();
  }

  /**
   * Get the boa for this model.
   *
   * @return App\Models\Boa
   */
  public function boa()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Points', 'boa_id')->withTrashed();
  }

  /**
   * Get the boa for this model.
   *
   * @return App\Models\Boa
   */
  public function pvd()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\CustomersPvds', 'pvd_id')->withTrashed();
  }


  /**
   * Get the boa for this model.
   *
   * @return App\Models\Boa
   */
  public function cartzone()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\CartZones', 'cartzone_id')->withTrashed();
  }

  /**
   * Get the parent for this model.
   *
   * @return App\Models\Parent
   */
  public function parent()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Parent', 'parent_id')->withTrashed();
  }

  /**
   * Get the user for this model.
   *
   * @return App\Models\User
   */
  public function user()
  {
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\Users', 'user_id')->withTrashed();
  }


  /**
   * Get created_at in array format
   *
   * @param string $value
   * @return array
   */
  public function getCreatedAtAttribute($value)
  {
    return \DateTime::createFromFormat($this->getDateFormat(), $value)->format('d/m/Y H:i:s');
  }

  /**
   * Get data in array format
   *
   * @param string $value
   * @return string
   */
  public function getDataRawAttribute($value)
  {
    return Carbon::createFromFormat('d/m/Y H:is', $this->created_at)->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
  }

}
```

*Query*

```
$pointsCartZone = Points::where('cart_zone_id', $trip->cart_zone_id)
        ->where('enabled', 1)
        ->select('*', DB::raw('(select COUNT(*) as ch from events where boa_id = points.id and schedule_id = ' . $id . ') as passed'))
        ->get();
```

Comment: Please provide more context. eg. Your models, models relationship and the result that you want to obtain. ;) an eg https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46395369/laravel-fractal-transformers-not-getting-includes

Comment: Please provide the generated SQL; I can help you optimize it, then you will have to reverse the process to figure out how to express that in Laravel.  (Or you can use my "raw" query.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to put on events table the index on boa_id and schedule_id and on points table on cart_zone_id.
let me know if it works :-)

Comment: thanks it works like a sharm from 1.76sec to 0.008sec